# How to render appropriate dropdown options in redux-forms/final-forms?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-form

I am building the basic country and region form using react and redux-forms.

I am facing the problem of rendering the regions according to the country selected by the user.

How do I pass/tell the selected country value to region dropdown and render accordingly ?

EDIT: At present I don't have any component level state.

The field components:

```
   <Field
        component={this.renderDropDown}
        data={countries}
        name="country"
        label="Country"
   />

   <Field
        component={this.renderDropDown}
        data={regions}
        name="Region"
        label="Region"
   />
```

The renderDropDown method:

```
  renderDropDown = ({data,label,input}) => {
  const renderedOptions = data.map(item => {
       return <option key={item.key} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
});

return (
  <div className="field">
    <label htmlFor="state">{label}</label>
    <select className="ui dropdown" {...input}>
        <option value="">State</option>
        {renderedOptions}
    </select>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: you need an onChange attribute on the select

Comment: When I use the onChange attr it doesn't change the values of the dropdown neither submit the selected option. However, the callback function on onChange executes successfully.

Comment: look at my answer I gave you a better example

Answer (score 0):

this what what your missing

```
const [selected,setSelected]=useState(null)

return(
    <select value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>            
           <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    </select>
)
```